# Convert Hex To unsigned long integer in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have value like this

```
DECLARE @hex VARCHAR(64) = '00E0'
```

and I need to convert this value to a double.

I have code in C language

```
double conver_str_to_temp(char *strTemp)
{
    int iTemp;
    double fTemp;

    iTemp = strtoul(strTemp, 0, 16); //strTemp is the string get from the message.
    if (iTemp & 0x8000)         //This means this is a negative value
    {
        iTemp -= 0x10000;
    }

    fTemp = iTemp * 0.0625;

    return fTemp;
}
```

Result for :`'00E0'` is `14.000000`

Result for : `'FF6B'`  is `-9.312500`

But problem is I'm not good in T-SQL.

How can I convert this C code to T-SQL function for use in SQL Server ?

Comment: what SQL server are you using?

Comment: What number do you expect to get from 00E0 in your example? And what's the value of `iTemp` in this case?

Comment: Result for :'00E0' is 14.000000

Result for : 'FF6B' is -9.312500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no function to convert a string containing a hexadecimal value to a number directly. But you can use intermediate conversion to `varbinary`, which could then be easily converted to an integer.

However, when converting to a `varbinary`, you will need to specify the correct format, so that the string is interpreted as a hexadecimal value (rather than a string of arbitrary digits and letters). This

```
CONVERT(varbinary, '00E0')
```

which in fact defaults to `CONVERT(varbinary, '00E0', 0)`, will result in every character being converted individually, because that's what the `0` format specifier does. So, every `'0'` will be converted to `0x30` and `'E'` to `0x45`, which will ultimately give you `0x30304530` – most probably not the result you want.

In contrast, this

```
CONVERT(varbinary, '00E0', 2)
```

results in `0x00E0`, because the `2` format specifier tells the function to interpret the string as a (non-prefixed) hexadecimal value.

Now that you've got the correct `varbinary` representation of the string, you can use either of the methods [suggested by @armen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17359412/297408) to convert the value to an integer: like this

```
CONVERT(varbinary, '00E0', 2) * 1
```

or like this:

```
CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, '00E0', 2))
```

To explain the former method a little, it uses implicit conversion: since the other operand of multiplication, `1`, is an `int` and `int` has higher precedence than `varbinary`, the `varbinary` operand is implicitly converted to `int` (which gives `224` in this particular case) before the multiplication can take place.

You can read more about conversion [in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: one thing that i still can't figure out is that both our answers give wrong result for the OP, as in his example result for : `00E0'` is `14.000000` and result for : `'FF6B'` is `-9.312500` ! am i missing something ?

Comment: @armen: I guess the hex number should actually be converted to a `smallint` rather than `int`, although there would still appear to be inconsistency. However, my guess is there's also a typo on the OP's part. I mean, it would be all right for `00E0`: `00E0h -> 224; 224 * 0.0625 = 14`. As for `FF9B`, it would be like this: `FF9Bh -> -101; -101 * 0.0625 = -6.3125`. The OP's expected result for `FF9B` is `-9.3125`, and that's where I'm inclined to think they've made a typo.

Answer (score 2):

try this-:

```
DECLARE @hex VARCHAR(64) = '00E0'

SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY, @hex) * 1
-- OR
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, @hex))
```

Comment: I GET ERROR Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3
Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.

Comment: what is your sql-server version ?

Comment: result  after *0.0625   Result for :'00E0' is 14.000000

Result for : 'FF6B' is -9.312500

Comment: could it be that this is scientific notation? like 5E3 = 5000?

Comment: `CONVERT(varbinary, '...')` will not regard the string as a hexadecimal value but instead will convert every character individually. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in TSQL, you need not employ a conversion function, 
SQL Server will convert the HEX value into the integer intrinsically.

in your case you can do the below

```
declare @hex float
set @hex = 00E0
select @hex
```

Comment: Please read the question. The parameter containing hex value is a `varchar`.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, he is taking the value into a varchar... instead he can also take it as an int, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on the problem at hand, as descried my OP. There is no need of a function (and question hence) if the argument is a numeric one.

Comment: @SurendraNathGM result should like that after *0.0625 Result for :'00E0' is 14.000000 AND Result for : 'FF6B' is -9.312500  but I get 0